# Get html after manipulating the html content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my js function, I want to change the attribute of certain elements inside a div, then I need to pass the html content of that div to another function. However, the html I obtained by using html() method is not changed. How can I get the html after the change? The code is shown below:

```js
function copyDiv() {
  //set the content of the textarea
  $('#text_field').val("test");
  
  //get the content of the textarea, the content is changed
  alert($('#text_field').val());
        
  //get the html content and set it to the new div
  //However, this html is not changed
  $('#newDiv').html( $('#myDiv').html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="text_field">text: </label>
 
  <textarea class="form-control" id="text_field"></textarea>
</div>

<div id='newDiv'>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="copyDiv();">test</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the value of **textarea** to the new element too?

Comment: Yes, exactly! @Anson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code to copy the value of the textarea to the new textarea after the HTML is duplicated, since this value isn't part of the DOM (and won't come along automatically).

I also removed the ID attribute from the textarea, since you can't have multiple elements on one page with the same ID, which your code was resulting in.

```js
function copyDiv() {
  $formControl = $('#myDiv .form-control');

  //set the content of the textarea
  $formControl.val("test");
  
  //get the content of the textarea, the content is changed
  alert($formControl.val());
        
  //get the html content and set it to the new div
  $('#newDiv').html( $('#myDiv').html());
  $('#newDiv .form-control').val( $formControl.val() );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="text_field">text: </label>
 
  <textarea class="form-control" name="text_field"></textarea>
</div>

<div id='newDiv'>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="copyDiv();">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery.clone()** instead of **.html()**.

Replace this

```
$('#newDiv').html( $('#myDiv').html());
```

to be this

```
$('#newDiv').html( $('#myDiv').clone());
```

Answer (score -1):

- You can try the following code,in case you want to set the content inside the text area you should use this code `$('#text_field').text("test");` and set the inner text of the text area.
- In case you want to change the value attribute you can use this code `$('#text_field').attr("value","test");`.The rest of the code is the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tring Reset</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="text_field">text: </label>
 
  <textarea class="form-control" id="text_field"></textarea>
</div>

<div id='newDiv'>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="copyDiv();">test</button> 
<script>
function copyDiv() {
   //set the content of the textarea
   $('#text_field').text("test");
   //to set the value attribute of th text area
   $('#text_field').attr("value","test");
   
   //get the content of the textarea, the content is changed
   alert($('#text_field').text());
         
   //get the html content and set it to the new div
   //However, this html is not changed
   $('#newDiv').html( $('#myDiv').html());
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```